# Python, rrdtool create - time stamp, timezone

Tags: python, timezone, ubuntu-10.04, epoch, rrdtool

Hello everybody in the house!

my python script creates an rrd file. The create_rrd and update function is started with the values "interval" and "starttime" (current epoch). The epoch time is correct when the functions are used. BUT: Doing an rrdtool fetch on the rrd file, the last time stamp is everytime 2 hours ago. My trick of calling subprocess.Popen with the ENV 'TZ' doesn't work.
So all rrd file updates fail.
Does anybody knows why, what I am doing wrong?

Best regards
Stefan

```
    def create_rrd(self, interval, starttime):
    interval = str(interval)
    interval_mins = float(interval) / 60
    heartbeat = str(int(interval) * 2)
    ds_string = 'DS:test:GAUGE:%s:U:U' % heartbeat
    rra_1 = 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:' + str(int(4000 / interval_mins))
    rra_2 = 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:' +  str(int(30 / interval_mins)) + ':800'
    rra_3 = 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:' + str(int(120 / interval_mins)) + ':800'
    rra_4 = 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:' + str(int(1440 / interval_mins)) + ':800'
    cmd_create = [
        '/omd/versions/default/bin/rrdtool',
        'create',
        self.rrd_name,
        '-b',
        str(starttime-10),
        '--step',
        interval,
        ds_string,
        rra_1,
        rra_2,
        rra_3 ,
        rra_4,
    ]
    print cmd_create
    cmd = Popen(cmd_create, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env={'LANG':'de_DE@euro','TZ':'Europe/Berlin'})
    cmd_output = cmd.communicate()
    self.errorprint(cmd_output)
    #p = Popen(["date"], env={'TZ':'America/New_York'})
    #p.wait()
    #p = Popen(["date"], env={'TZ':'Europe/Berlin'})
    #p.wait()


def update(self, starttime, *values):
    values_args = ''.join([str(value) + ':' for value in values])[:-1]
    values_final = '%s:%s' % (str(starttime), values_args)
    cmd_update = [
                '/omd/versions/default/bin/rrdtool',
                'update',
                self.rrd_name,
                values_final,
    ]
    print cmd_update
    cmd = Popen(cmd_update, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env={'LANG':'de_DE@euro','TZ':'Europe/Berlin'})
    cmd_output = cmd.communicate()
    self.errorprint(cmd_output
```

Here is the command list of the Popen for create and update:

```
rrd create
['/omd/versions/default/bin/rrdtool', 'create', '/tmp/test1/CPU_utilization_util.rrd', '-b', '1342630417', '--step', '300', 'DS:test:GAUGE:600:U:U', 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:800', 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:6:800', 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:24:800', 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:800']
rrd update
['/omd/versions/default/bin/rrdtool', 'update', '/tmp/test1/CPU_utilization_util.rrd', '1342630427:8.37649086759']
```

Comment: note that numeric timestamps are always in epoch time and not in localtime, the value of TZ only has an effect for formatted time output ... in rrdtool graph (and when using AT style time input)